# SimpleHtmlDom Edit and Save file

Tags: php, html, parsing

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Looking to parse through an HTML file, make some small changes, and overwrite the current file with the updates. Was wondering if this was possible through simplehtmldom

As of right now, I can access everything, but have no way of displaying the entirely of the HTML With all of the changes included. Is it only possible to grab specific values?

If so, what other methods could I use to accomplish this? I'm afraid the environment I have to work in is extremely limited due to security issues.

Comment: in what ways is your environment limited? what *can* you do? and how does that relate to the question at hand? (given that you seem to be able to use the simplehtmldom software itself without problems)

Answer (score -1):

The simplehtmldom object can be used as a string, and will just contain the full contents of the modified document.

For example:

```
echo($html);
file_put_contents($filename, $html);
```

If you prefer an object-oriented method, you can use `save()`:

```
$updated = $html->save();
```

or

```
$html->save($filename);
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was downvoted. It's straight out of the **[simplehtmldom documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_dump)**